# explaining why React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm new to React, but why vs code is showing me this message in the problem tab
isn't adding currentNoteId to the dependence array will crash the app

```js
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [currentNoteId, setCurrentNoteId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentNoteId) {
      setCurrentNoteId(notes[0]?.id);
    }
  }, [notes]);
```

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'currentNoteId'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

I tried what vs code was suggesting but did not understand why, if you can tell me what's going on please

Comment: You should add `currentNoteId` also into the dependency array as `[currentNoteId,notes]`

Comment: Please do a basic google search and read the official documentation before posting a question to stack overflow. If you did those things but didn't understand them, please include that as well as what you *specifically* did not understand about them in the question.

Comment: The dependency array [must](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#specifying-reactive-dependencies) contain all state members (and other reactive values) used by the effect callback because otherwise the effect callback won't be called when it should be. For instance: We can say that your effect's code is supposed to ensure that `currentNoteId` is either `undefined` (if there are no notes) or a note ID (if there are), but the code doesn't accomplish that: If you had `setCurrentNoteId(undefined)` somewhere and called it when there were notes, the callback wouldn't...

Comment: ...get called, and `currentNoteId` would be `undefined` despite the fact there are notes. Now, it may be that you don't have anything that would do that in your code in your **specific** case, but the linter has to assume the **general** case.

Comment: It's worth noting that the code shown isn't using [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) for its intended purpose ([synchronizing with an external system](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects)). Instead, it's using it to perform a side-effect on a state member. You might instead consider using a wrapper around `setNotes` that also updates `currentNoteId` as needed, since what you currently have will cause two renders when `currentNoteId` needs updating: The render after updating `notes`, then another triggered by the effect callback updating `currentNoteId`.

Comment: Two basics ideas that should help inform your understanding of `useEffect()` are:
1. Effects are intended to synchronize your component with some external (non-React) system. They respond to renders, not to user-initiated events.
2. Effects react to "reactive" values

In my experience, when you find those warnings to be incorrect, there's a good chance you are abusing the effect "escape hatch" and don't need it at all! See [here](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) for some examples and [here](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects) for effect docs.